# jQuery on() or live

Tags: javascript, web, jquery, jquery-on

I'm trying to use the code below. It works fine on Firefox as expected but when I try IE or Chrome, the `on` or `live` methods don't fire. Can anybody help me about it?

```
$('#serverCpus').find('option').on('mouseenter', function (a) {
    a.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log('hihihi');
});
```

Comment: provide your HTML too.. or some errors if you are getting one... or something that we can test with or some information if the option is added dynamically or sumthing......how will we be able to solve the problem with provided information only

Comment: mousenter an option ? Does that really make sense ?

Comment: What's your goal with hooking `mouseenter` on `option` elements?

Comment: could you share jsfiddle for your complete code

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/v67dN/

Comment: +1 for the fiddle by @eicto. infact your code works too. There might be some other problem.

Comment: eicto, your solution work fine on jsfiddle, but on my page no make sense. My designer used jquery version 1.5.1

Comment: If you are using jQuery 1.5.1, I would not expect that handler to work in any browser. The `.on()` method was added to jQuery in version 1.7. If you are using the older version of jQuery, `.live()` or `.delegate()` would be my suggestions. However, IE does not seem to trigger mouse movement events on select options.

Comment: It is hard to tell what you need to do once the event has been fired but if you are waiting for a selection option to be selected why not use .change() on the select

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$('option').on('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log('mouse just entered an option')
}
```